# Odd HTML spacing only in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

On a [proof](http://zslabs.com/sample/cofc/) I'm mocking up, there is a random space forcing a horizontal scrollbar that I cannot find the cause of. Oddly enough, this is only happening in Firefox (16 - Mac + PC). If you load up that page, you'll see a black line on the right of the page (in the "header" area). Firebug isn't helping much here and only seems to go away when I clear the contents of the main `.container`. I'm honestly a bit lost here as I've never seen Firefox of all things give me trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

styles.css (line 764) -- remove `right: -25px;` and it goes away... Hope it helps!

Looks like it doesn't affect anything visibly either.

Comment: Appreciate you looking at that - doing that makes the `:before` show up fine and `:after` but it is then not positioned correctly (at least that is consistent through all browsers). Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does adding `margin-right: 25px;` in the same place instead work cross-browser? It looks right in chrome and FF.  Though FF doesn't have those little bar doohickeys that chrome has at all.

Comment: Yeah the doohickeys are the key ;) definitely frustrating

Comment: If it's that difficult to fix and it's really only in firefox, maybe you should just add a browser-specific rule for firefox.  Or use a real element.  At least you know what that line is now. :)

Comment: Upvote it is then ;) I'll keep plugging away. Appreciate the help